# Network bridging on windows

Tags: windows, networking, bridge

I have a network on only one Ethernet NIC and is connected on the internet.
I have second IP on the same network card, and i need to bring the second network on the internet.
If i make a virtual microsoft loopback card, on the same range as the second ip, delete the second ip from the first network nic, and bridge the two network cards together, will be ok to have internet and Local access to each network from windows?

The default Ethernet network 192.168.1.0/24 is connected on the internet. The same card has a second ip-network is assigned on then same interface, 192.168.20.1/24 with some devices connected to this network, like pda's via a wlan access point and other connections via ethernet on the same second network. I need to share the internet connection to those 2 networks, and i suppose by creating a virtual nic and bridge it to the first one would be fine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.